# Crossthread exception and invokerequired solution doesn't change my control value

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

**EDIT Solution :**

**Here i'm setting my byref value in each object then i'm running a backgroundworker**

```
Private Sub TelechargeFichier()

    Dim DocManquant As Boolean = False
    Dim docName As String = ""
    Dim lg As String = ""
    Dim telechargementFini As Boolean = False

    lblMessage.Text = EasyDealChangeLanguage.Instance.GetStringFromResourceName("1478")

    prgBar.Maximum = m_listeFichiers.Count

    For i As Integer = 0 To m_listeFichiers.Count - 1

        m_listeFichiers(i).Set_ByRefLabel(lblMessage)
        m_listeFichiers(i).Set_ByRefPrgbar(prgBar)
        m_listeThreads.Add(New Thread(AddressOf m_listeFichiers(i).DownloadMe))

    Next


    m_bgWorker = New BackgroundWorker
    m_bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    AddHandler m_bgWorker.DoWork, AddressOf DownloadFiles
    m_bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()







    ''Completed
    'lblMessage.Text = EasyDealChangeLanguage.Instance.GetStringFromResourceName("1383")

    'Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK

End Sub
```

**Here is my downloadFiles function :
Note that each start will do the downloadMe function see below**

```
  Private Sub DownloadFiles(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)


    For i As Integer = 0 To m_listeThreads.Count - 1
        m_listeThreads(i).Start()
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To m_listeThreads.Count - 1
        m_listeThreads(i).Join()
    Next


End Sub
```

***PROBLEM HERE :***

I have multiple thread that each will download a ftp file.
I would like that each file that have been completed will set a value to a progress bar and a label from my UI thread.  For some reason invokerequired never change to false.

Here is my little function that start all the thread

```
 Private Sub TelechargeFichier()

    Dim DocManquant As Boolean = False
    Dim docName As String = ""
    Dim lg As String = ""
    Dim telechargementFini As Boolean = False

    lblMessage.Text = EasyDealChangeLanguage.Instance.GetStringFromResourceName("1478")

    prgBar.Maximum = m_listeFichiers.Count

    For i As Integer = 0 To m_listeFichiers.Count - 1

        m_listeFichiers(i).Set_ByRefLabel(lblMessage)
        m_listeFichiers(i).Set_ByRefPrgbar(prgBar)
        m_listeThreads.Add(New Thread(AddressOf m_listeFichiers(i).DownloadMe))

    Next


    For i As Integer = 0 To m_listeThreads.Count - 1
        m_listeThreads(i).Start()
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To m_listeThreads.Count - 1
        m_listeThreads(i).Join()
    Next

    'Completed
    lblMessage.Text = EasyDealChangeLanguage.Instance.GetStringFromResourceName("1383")

    Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK

End Sub
```

Here my property that hold the Byref control from the UI thread.
This is in my object which content the addressof function that will download the file (DownloadMe)

```
    Public Sub Set_ByRefPrgbar(ByRef prgbar As ProgressBar)

    m_prgBar = prgbar

End Sub
Public Sub Set_ByRefLabel(ByRef lbl As EasyDeal.Controls.EasyDealLabel3D)

    m_lblMessage = lbl

End Sub
```

Here is the download function :

```
   Public Sub DownloadMe()

    Dim ftpReq As FtpWebRequest
    Dim ftpResp As FtpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim streamInput As Stream
    Dim fileStreamOutput As FileStream

    Try

        ftpReq = CType(WebRequest.Create(EasyDeal.Controls.Common.FTP_CONNECTION & m_downloadFtpPath & m_filename), FtpWebRequest)
        ftpReq.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
        ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
        ftpResp = ftpReq.GetResponse
        streamInput = ftpResp.GetResponseStream()
        fileStreamOutput = New FileStream(m_outputPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        ReadWriteStream(streamInput, fileStreamOutput)

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Au pire la fichier sera pas downloader

    Finally

        If ftpResp IsNot Nothing Then
            ftpResp.Close()
        End If

        Dim nomFichier As String = m_displaynameEN

        If EasyDealChangeLanguage.GetCurrentLanguageTypes = EasyDealChangeLanguage.EnumLanguageType.Francais Then
            nomFichier = m_displaynameFR

        End If
        If m_lblMessage IsNot Nothing Then
            EasyDealCommon.TH_SetControlText(m_lblMessage, String.Format(EasyDealChangeLanguage.Instance.GetStringFromResourceName("1479"), nomFichier))

        End If
        If m_prgBar IsNot Nothing Then
            EasyDealCommon.TH_SetPrgValue(m_prgBar, 1)

        End If

    End Try



End Sub
```

Here is the crossthread invoke solution function :

```
    Public Sub TH_SetControlText(ByVal ctl As Control, ByVal text As String)

    If ctl.InvokeRequired Then

        ctl.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of Control, String)(AddressOf TH_SetControlText), ctl, text)

    Else

        ctl.Text = text

    End If

End Sub
Public Sub TH_SetPrgValue(ByVal prg As ProgressBar, ByVal value As Integer)

    If prg.InvokeRequired Then

        prg.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of ProgressBar, Integer)(AddressOf TH_SetPrgValue), prg, value)

    Else

        prg.Value += value

    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is the invokerequired never get to false it actually goes in to beginInvoke but never end in the Else section to set the value.

Comment: Oh, just for fun... you can replace `New Action(Of Control, String)(AddressOf TH_SetControlText), ctl, text` with just `Sub() TH_SetControlText(ctl, text)` :)

Comment: Also, if `InvokeRequired` is always true... does that mean you end up in an infinite loop? Shouldn't you get a `StackOverflowException` after awhile?

Comment: No loop after awhile..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the initial method, TelechargeFichier(), being fired from?  Is it in the main UI thread itself?

If so, then this portion is a problem:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To m_listeThreads.Count - 1
    m_listeThreads(i).Join()
Next
```

This is FREEZING the main thread until the other threads are completed.  This fits with your symptom of "it actually goes in to beginInvoke but never end in the Else section to set the value."  Since the main UI thread is frozen, waiting for the other threads to complete, it can't possibly execute your requests for BeginInvoke().

If you want to Join() and wait for the other threads to complete, do this within the DoWork() handler of a BackgroundWorker(), or some other suitable thread that is NOT the main UI thread.

Comment: Thanks ! solved my issue and is quite logic, anyway i updated my post with the solution

Answer (score 1):

With `invoke` you want to get "back" into the UI thread, to do some work there. Have you looked what your UI thread does? It starts the threads and then uses `.Join`. This will BLOCK the UI thread until all other threads are finished. That means that your update code can not run (even after begininvoke), because a blocked (UI)thread will not run it ;)

```
Public Class Form1

Private tm As New Threading.Timer(AddressOf tmcallback)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    tm.Change(0, 500)
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(Sub() Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000))
    t.Start()
    t.Join()
    tm.Change(-1, -1)


End Sub

Sub tmcallback()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Console.WriteLine("Required")
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() tmcallback())
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("NOT Required")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Notice the output: First all "required" show up and only after the UI thread unblocks all "NOT required" come up.